# Creating and adding TreeNodes to a Tree with LINQ?

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

Still trying to wrap my head around LINQ coming from the Java and Objective-C world. Is there a way to accomplish the following loop with LINQ?

```
        foreach(MyData d in mydata)
        {
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode(d.DisplayName);
            this.myTree.Nodes.Add(n);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myTree.Nodes.AddRange(myData.Select(n => new TreeNode(n.DisplayName)).ToArray());
```

Comment: thanks! I get an error though: "cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode>' to 'System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode[]'"

Comment: it was untested, i'll have another look

Comment: Ok have added ToArray() :)

Comment: OK I can't accept the answer for another 5 minutes. :) Thanks - examples like this really help.

Comment: Also added another bracket after the Select() so that we return an array of TreeNodes's and not call ToArray() on a new TreeNode itself..

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
myTree.Nodes.AddRange(myData.Select(n => new TreeNode(n.DisplayName)).ToArray());
```